# On migration in Django, I get error Integrity Error 1364, "Field 'id' doesn't have a default value"

Tags: django, mariadb

This is something that appeared after a few iterations of saving and restoring the MariaDB database. It doesn't matter how simple the change is, or what I'm changing, it will perform the migration, then throw this error.

```
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 71, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 250, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 50, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorvalue
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 247, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 412, in _query
    rowcount = self._do_query(q)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 375, in _do_query
    db.query(q)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 276, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
_mysql_exceptions.IntegrityError: (1364, "Field 'id' doesn't have a default value")
```

This is something I can work around just by ignoring it, but it's quite annoying and distracting. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This has been bugging me for years. Somewhere in the save and restore, the id fields of most of the django management tables lost their primary key and autoincrement properties, and started filling up with zeroes. I corrected this with the following Python 3.6 script:

```
import MySQLdb

dbspec = {
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'USER': 'user',
    'PASSWORD': 'badpassword',
    'NAME': 'databasename'
}

def reserialize1(cnx, tablename, truekey, makekey='id'):

    sql = f"select max({makekey}) from {tablename}"
    cur = cnx.cursor()
    cur.execute(sql)
    response = cur.fetchall()
    maxid = response[0][0]
    counter = maxid + 1

    sql = f"select {makekey}, {truekey} from {tablename}"
    cur = cnx.cursor()
    cur.execute(sql)
    response = cur.fetchall()
    cur = cnx.cursor()
    for itr in response:
        if itr[0] == 0:
            sql = f"update {tablename} set {makekey}={counter} where {truekey}='{itr[1]}'"
            print(f"running {sql}")
            cur.execute(sql)
        counter += 1
    cnx.commit()


def reserialize2(cnx, tablename, key1, key2, makekey='id'):

    sql = f"select max({makekey}) from {tablename}"
    cur = cnx.cursor()
    cur.execute(sql)
    response = cur.fetchall()
    maxid = response[0][0]
    counter = maxid + 1

    sql = f"select {makekey}, {key1}, {key2} from {tablename}"
    cur = cnx.cursor()
    cur.execute(sql)
    response = cur.fetchall()
    cur = cnx.cursor()
    for itr in response:
        if itr[0] == 0:
            sql = f"update {tablename} set {makekey}={counter} " \
                  f"where {key1}='{itr[1]}' and {key2}='{itr[2]}'"
            print(f"running {sql}")
            cur.execute(sql)
        counter += 1
    cnx.commit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cnx = MySQLdb.connect(host=dbspec['HOST'],
                               user=dbspec['USER'],
                               passwd=dbspec['PASSWORD'],
                               db=dbspec['NAME'])
    reserialize1(cnx, 'auth_permission', 'codename')
    reserialize2(cnx, 'auth_user_groups', 'user_id', 'group_id')
    reserialize1(cnx, 'django_admin_log', 'action_time')
    reserialize2(cnx, 'django_content_type', 'app_label', 'model')
    reserialize1(cnx, 'django_migrations', 'applied')

    cur = cnx.cursor()
    cur.execute("ALTER TABLE auth_group MODIFY COLUMN id INT primary key auto_increment;")
    cur.execute("ALTER TABLE auth_group_permissions MODIFY COLUMN id INT primary key auto_increment;")
    cur.execute("ALTER TABLE auth_permission MODIFY COLUMN id INT primary key auto_increment;")
    cur.execute("ALTER TABLE auth_user_groups MODIFY COLUMN id INT primary key auto_increment;")
    cur.execute("ALTER TABLE auth_user_user_permissions MODIFY COLUMN id INT primary key auto_increment;")
    cur.execute("ALTER TABLE django_admin_log MODIFY COLUMN id INT primary key auto_increment;")
    cur.execute("ALTER TABLE django_content_type MODIFY COLUMN id INT primary key auto_increment;")
    cur.execute("ALTER TABLE django_migrations MODIFY COLUMN id INT primary key auto_increment;")
    cnx.commit()
```